# SharePoint database admin account accidentally deleted

Tags: administration, configuration, database, delete, farm

The SharePoint database admin accidentally deleted. How to reinstate this admin account?

I created a new account with `db_owner` in database. But looks like it was not setup properly.

It shows below error while open the site:

> "This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products"

It shows below error in even log:

> "There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database “”, and connections to the data have been blocked to due to this incompatibility. This can happen when a content database has not been upgraded to be within the compatibility range of the Web server, or if the database has been upgraded to a higher level than the web server. The Web server and the database must be upgraded to the same version and build level to return to compatibility range"

It shows below error while try to get-spfarm:

> "Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again".

Comment: When you say 'database admin' - do you mean the SharePoint farm account?

Comment: yes, @Christoffer, which was created in database automatically while sharepoint farm built